# Missing events/items when combining findAll, flatMap and Schedulers.boundedElastic()

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have written the following test while exploring spring webflux.
It's quite simple, i thought. Writing 10000 items and reading them again.
But somehow, sometimes a few are missing.
There no is no exception thrown just sometimes missing a few.
Is this a coding error or maybe a bug in mongo / reactor?
This is a basic spring boot setup without any further customization.
Thx.

```
package de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.persistence.DataA;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.persistence.DataB;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.repository.DataARepository;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.repository.DataBRepository;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.service.DataService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
public class DataServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    DataARepository dataARepository;
    
    @Autowired
    DataBRepository dataBRepository;

    @Autowired
    DataService dataService;

    @BeforeEach
    void before() {
        dataARepository.deleteAll().block();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            String value = String.valueOf(i);
            dataARepository.save(new DataA(value, value)).block();
        }
        
        dataBRepository.deleteAll().block();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String value = String.valueOf(i);
            dataBRepository.save(new DataB(value, value)).block();
        }
    }

    @RepeatedTest(1)
    void findAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int size = dataService.findAll().size();
            log.debug("size = {}", size);
            assertEquals(10000, size);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.service;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.persistence.DataA;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.repository.DataARepository;
import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.repository.DataBRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class DataService {

    private final DataARepository dataARepository;
    private final DataBRepository dataBRepository;

    private Mono<DataA> map(DataA dataA) {
        return Mono.just(dataA).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }

    public Collection<DataA> findAll() {
        return dataARepository.findAll().onErrorContinue((t, o) -> t.printStackTrace()).flatMap(this::map).collectList()
                .block();
    }
}
```

```
package de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.persistence.DataA;

@Repository
public interface DataARepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<DataA, String> {
}
```

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
22:04:02.279 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
22:04:02.293 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
22:04:02.327 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
22:04:02.343 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
22:04:02.348 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]: class path resource [de/eggheads/tools/fluxtest/DataServiceTests-context.xml] does not exist
22:04:02.348 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]: class path resource [de/eggheads/tools/fluxtest/DataServiceTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
22:04:02.348 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
22:04:02.349 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]: DataServiceTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
22:04:02.393 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]
22:04:02.458 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\dev\eclipse-2020-12\ws\fluxtest\target\classes\de\eggheads\tools\fluxtest\FluxtestApplication.class]
22:04:02.470 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.FluxtestApplication for test class de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests
22:04:02.571 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests]: using defaults.
22:04:02.572 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
22:04:02.587 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
22:04:02.598 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@2dd80673, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@4af0df05, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@57ea113a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@acdb094, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@674bd420, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@2b0f373b, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@2ceb80a1, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@4b45dcb8, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@7216fb24, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@2072acb2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@50ecde95, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@35a9782c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@70a36a66, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@45815ffc]
22:04:02.603 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@5b068087 testClass = DataServiceTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@6f152006 testClass = DataServiceTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.FluxtestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1807f5a7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4dc27487, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1b66c0fb, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@660acfb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2d29b4ee, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@3b6d844d, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@78047b92], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
22:04:02.628 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@5b068087 testClass = DataServiceTests, testInstance = de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests@5ee2b6f9, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@6f152006 testClass = DataServiceTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class de.eggheads.tools.fluxtest.FluxtestApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1807f5a7, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4dc27487, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@1b66c0fb, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@660acfb, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@2d29b4ee, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@3b6d844d, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@78047b92], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]].
22:04:02.662 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-12 22:04:02.963  INFO 18824 --- [           main] d.e.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests      : Starting DataServiceTests using Java 11.0.9.1 on egg-note58 with PID 18824 (started by christianl in C:\dev\eclipse-2020-12\ws\fluxtest)
2021-04-12 22:04:02.965  INFO 18824 --- [           main] d.e.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-12 22:04:03.469  INFO 18824 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-12 22:04:03.655  INFO 18824 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 182 ms. Found 2 Reactive MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-04-12 22:04:05.646  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
2021-04-12 22:04:05.708  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.708+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=18632 port=62655 dbpath=C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-2b40d458-5827-4772-ae88-9721f76da138 64-bit host=egg-note58
2021-04-12 22:04:05.708  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008
2021-04-12 22:04:05.708  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.5.5
2021-04-12 22:04:05.708  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 98515c812b6fa893613f063dae568ff8319cbfbd
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.709+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", http: { enabled: false }, port: 62655 }, security: { authorization: "disabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp\embedmongo-db-2b40d458-5827-4772-ae88-9721f76da138", journal: { enabled: false }, mmapv1: { preallocDataFiles: false, smallFiles: true }, syncPeriodSecs: 0.0 } }
2021-04-12 22:04:05.709  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.710+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=15766M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=0,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),,log=(enabled=false),
2021-04-12 22:04:05.788  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.789+0200 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected configuration for non-active storage engine mmapv1 when current storage engine is wiredTiger
2021-04-12 22:04:05.788  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.789+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-04-12 22:04:05.788  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.789+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a development version (3.5.5) of MongoDB.
2021-04-12 22:04:05.789  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.789+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **       Not recommended for production.
2021-04-12 22:04:05.789  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:05.789+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-04-12 22:04:06.151  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.152+0200 W FTDC     [initandlisten] Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC: WindowsPdhError: PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'Das angegebene Objekt wurde nicht auf dem Computer gefunden.' for counter '\Memory\Available Bytes'
2021-04-12 22:04:06.151  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.152+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'C:/Users/CHRIST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/embedmongo-db-2b40d458-5827-4772-ae88-9721f76da138/diagnostic.data'
2021-04-12 22:04:06.187  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.188+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { version: 1 }, name: "incompatible_with_version_32", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2021-04-12 22:04:06.187  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.188+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2021-04-12 22:04:06.189  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.190+0200 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
2021-04-12 22:04:06.190  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.191+0200 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
2021-04-12 22:04:06.191  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:06.192+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 62655
2021-04-12 22:04:06.191  INFO 18824 --- [           main] d.f.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable         : start de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder$ImmutableMongodConfig@16a9eb2e
2021-04-12 22:04:06.439  INFO 18824 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:62655], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-04-12 22:04:07.344  INFO 18824 --- [           main] d.e.tools.fluxtest.DataServiceTests      : Started DataServiceTests in 4.669 seconds (JVM running for 5.804)
2021-04-12 22:04:07.378  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.378+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62710 #1 (1 connection now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:07.378  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.378+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62711 #2 (2 connections now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:07.423  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.423+0200 I NETWORK  [conn2] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:62711 conn2: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams|spring-boot", version: "4.1.2" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/AdoptOpenJDK/11.0.9.1+1" }
2021-04-12 22:04:07.423  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.423+0200 I NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:62710 conn1: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams|spring-boot", version: "4.1.2" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/AdoptOpenJDK/11.0.9.1+1" }
2021-04-12 22:04:07.450  INFO 18824 --- [localhost:62655] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2}] to localhost:62655
2021-04-12 22:04:07.450  INFO 18824 --- [localhost:62655] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to localhost:62655
2021-04-12 22:04:07.451  INFO 18824 --- [localhost:62655] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:62655, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=65840300}
2021-04-12 22:04:07.903  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.903+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62713 #3 (3 connections now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:07.909  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:07.909+0200 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:62713 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|reactive-streams|spring-boot", version: "4.1.2" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/AdoptOpenJDK/11.0.9.1+1" }
2021-04-12 22:04:07.912  INFO 18824 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-3] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:3}] to localhost:62655
2021-04-12 22:04:14.110  INFO 18824 --- [extShutdownHook] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:3}] to localhost:62655 because the pool has been closed.
2021-04-12 22:04:14.112  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:14.113+0200 I -        [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:62713 (3 connections now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:14.113  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:14.113+0200 I -        [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:62710 (2 connections now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:14.113  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:14.113+0200 I -        [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:62711 (1 connection now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:62715 #4 (1 connection now open)
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I COMMAND  [conn4] terminating, shutdown command received
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I NETWORK  [conn4] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I NETWORK  [conn4] closing listening socket: 540
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I NETWORK  [conn4] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2021-04-12 22:04:16.206  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.206+0200 I FTDC     [conn4] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2021-04-12 22:04:16.212  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.212+0200 I STORAGE  [conn4] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2021-04-12 22:04:16.307  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.307+0200 I STORAGE  [conn4] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2021-04-12 22:04:16.308  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.307+0200 I CONTROL  [conn4] now exiting
2021-04-12 22:04:16.308  INFO 18824 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-04-12T22:04:16.307+0200 I CONTROL  [conn4] shutting down with code:0
```

Comment: also please post your logs of the test failure

Comment: A `Flux` contains multiple `Monos` so can you please explain to me why you are unwrapping each `Mono` in your `Flux` and then rewrapping it in a `Mono` and applying a `boundedElastic` scheduler to each as this doesn't make any sense. Documentation clearly states that schedulers applied in `subscribeOn` are applied once when someone subscribes, and the first found scheduler in the chain will be used. Adding 10000 wont make any difference. I think you need to read up in the reactor documentation. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_subscribeon_method

Comment: you can straight off remove the entire `map` function.

Comment: My original intention was to construct a domain object from the repositories, that's where I encountered this issue.
I know this example makes no sense, but i tried to simplify it as much as possible, still showing the undesired outcome.
You are most certainly right, I have to read a lot more, and more importantly understand a lot more.
So be assured, I very much appreciate your answer.
After all, it just might be the case, that I totally misused the API.
As I said, just started to explore.

Comment: I added the log, cant paste the assertion error, too long, starts: org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <10000> but was: <9998>

Comment: I will try to reproduce the original issue, and keep your hint in mind, that the subscription is propagated for the whole chain, thx!